# Accessing a generic dictionary via casting at runtime

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection, casting

Our program has a dictionary of type:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TCache>();
```

where TKey and TCache are whatever generic types the encompassing method is given, and TCache is a CacheBase.

In another method I need to reference this object (which is stored in another dictionary where it's stored as an object) and remove a key/value pair from it. At runtime I have the TKey object boxed as an 'object' class.

How would I go about this? I can't cast to Dictionary because this method is not generic and won't know at compile time what type of cache/key it is. These are passed as parameters.

Is there a way to use reflection to cast the dictionary from Dictionary to effectively

```
Dictionary<CacheBase<key.GetType()>, key.GetType()>
```

I know this can easily fixed by not using the methods generics and instead making the Dictionary a Dictionary and making CaseBase extend an empty CacheBase, but my supervisor insisted I do it this way

Comment: Generics are compile time resolved. You cannot resolve a generic type during runtime with reflection.

Comment: Is `CacheBase` the interface for other derivative types?  Are you sure the key is generic or is it a property of `CacheBase`?

Comment: `Dictionary<T,V>` implements a non-generic interface `IDictionary`. Perhaps you could access it through that. But in general if you don't have compile-time types, then using generics is just going to create more pain than they are worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it on my own, but for future people,

Essentially, I had to flip the perspective. I can't cast an existing dictionary to another equivalent type via reflection, however the goal was to do so so I could modify the dictionary with Types at runtime.

So instead, I made a generic method that would communicate with the dictionary in the way it wanted (if it expects a TKey, I made my method take a TKey so it would work properly).

e.g.

```
public void RemoveFromCache<TCache, TKey>( Type type, TKeykey ) where TCache : CacheBase<TKey> {
  ((Dictionary<TKey, TCache>)m_caches[type]).Remove( key );
}
```

After that, I simply used reflection to call my generic method at runtime with the types passed in as the appropriate generics

e.g.

```
var keyType = key.GetType();
var removeFromCache = GetType().GetMethod( nameof( RemoveFromCache ) ).MakeGenericMethod( type, keyType );
removeFromCache.Invoke( this, new object[] { type, key } );
```

And that let me communicate with a Dictionary that was boxed into an object at runtime with only types available.